# Sending data from variable to sql query in pandas read_sql(')

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I want to send start date and end date value into my sql query from 2 separate variables. Suppose,
I have start_date = '2020-05-14' and end_date = '2020-07-08' stored in a variable. Now my query is:

```
db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/table_name'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
def myfunc(start_date, end_date):
    sql_syn = "SELECT col_id, col_a, col_b, date, FROM en_stat where date between :start_date and :end_date"
    sql_df = pd.read_sql(sql_syn, con=db_connection, chunksize=100)
```

how to pass the start_date and end_date values dynamically for this particular code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `python3` [`f-strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
def myfunc(start_date, end_date):
    sql_syn = f"SELECT col_id, col_a, col_b, date, FROM en_stat where date between {start_date} and {end_date}"
    sql_df = pd.read_sql(sql_syn, con=db_connection, chunksize=100)
```